# export data from SQL Server to a file(.csv)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to export data from a table in SQL Server to a file type (. csv)   with this command:

```
bcp test.dbo.user out "user.csv" -T -c -t";"-S"DELL\DELLL"
```

as test is my DataBase,user is the table to export, Dell is the server and DELLL is the user.

but I got this error

> Unable to open the data file of the host BCP

Comment: If you switch the language in SQL Server to english then you can add the english error message. `Set Language 'us_english'`

Comment: `-S` is for specifying `Server\IntanceName` not server and User. `-S server_name[ \instance_name]
Specifies the instance of SQL Server to which to connect. If no server is specified, the bcp utility connects to the default instance of SQL Server on the local computer. This option is required when a bcp command is run from a remote computer on the network or a local named instance. To connect to the default instance of SQL Server on a server, specify only server_name. To connect to a named instance of SQL Server, specify server_name\instance_name.`

Comment: yes actually DELLL is the instance of SQL Server to which I connect

Comment: if you are trying to export from server you are already connected I would just leave out -S option.